# Problem with ROS control and Gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-kinetic, gazebo-ros-control

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have a problem with controlling a URDF that I exported from SolidWorks. (Ubuntu 16.04 , Kinetic, Gazebo 7.x)
I followed [this tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_control) and I wanted to implemented on my robot. All the controllers are starting correctly so as the Gazebo simulation also the Node publish the data correctly I have checked it with echo-ing the topic and with different values for the data. Is there a chance not working because the PID values ?

All the transmissions look like this :

```
<transmission name="tran1">
<type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
<joint name="Joint_1">
  <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
</joint>
<actuator name="motor1">
  <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
  <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
</actuator>
</transmission>
```

The controller is like this (for all joints) :

```
joint_state_controller:
    type: joint_state_controller/JointStateController
    publish_rate: 50
joint1_position_controller:
    type: effort_controllers/JointPositionController
    joint: Joint_1
    pid: {p: 100.0, i: 0.01, d: 10.0}
```

And I have this node:

```
rospy.init_node('ArmMovement')
pub1=rospy.Publisher("/rrbot/joint1_position_controller/command",Float64,queue_size=10 )
rate = rospy.Rate(50)
ArmCor1= Float64()
ArmCor1.data=0
pub1.publish(ArmCor1)
rate.sleep()
```

Edit#1 :
Part of URDF for the Joint_1:

```
 <joint name="Joint_1" type="revolute">
<origin
  xyz="0 0 -0.008"
  rpy="1.5708 0 0" />
<parent link="base_link" />
<child link="Link_1" />
<axis
  xyz="0 1 0" />
<limit
  lower="0"
  upper="3.14"
  effort="0"
  velocity="0" />
 </joint>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/336795/problem-with-ros-control-and-gazebo./) by [MichaelDUEE](https://answers.ros.org/users/37459/michaelduee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2019-11-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pmuthu2s](https://answers.ros.org/users/33024/pmuthu2s/) on 2019-11-04**:
What is the behavior that you are seeing? IS it vibrating?

**Comment by [MichaelDUEE](https://answers.ros.org/users/37459/michaelduee/) on 2019-11-04**:
@pmuthu2s It has a little vibration but I believe it occurs because the gripper of the arm is touching the ground. There is no movement further than that.

**Comment by [Jasmin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28536/jasmin/) on 2019-11-06**:
Are there any warnings or errors when running your simulation? Is Gazebo loading your controllers correctly, is it publishing on the topic "/rrbot/joint1_position_controller/state" and subscribing to "/rrbot/joint1_position_controller/command" as expected?

**Comment by [MichaelDUEE](https://answers.ros.org/users/37459/michaelduee/) on 2019-11-06**:
No I dont have any warning or errors. The controllers are starting correclty and the message is successfully transimitted. @Jasmin

**Comment by [Jasmin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28536/jasmin/) on 2019-11-06**:
Could you post your urdf or at least the joint definition part?

**Comment by [MichaelDUEE](https://answers.ros.org/users/37459/michaelduee/) on 2019-11-06**:
@Jasmin. Of course, I have edited the question!

**Comment by [Jasmin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28536/jasmin/) on 2019-11-07**:
That helps! The joint will never move with a velocity="0". You need to set non zero effort and velocity values, try something like:

```
<limit
  lower="0"
  upper="3.14"
  effort="2"
  velocity="2.0" />
```

**Comment by [MichaelDUEE](https://answers.ros.org/users/37459/michaelduee/) on 2019-11-12**:
@Jasmin Thank you a lot for your help, it actually works!!

**Comment by [Jasmin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28536/jasmin/) on 2019-11-13**:
@MichaelDUEE  You're welcome! Happy it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you guys for your help, it actually work after your comments.
This was my Joint_1 :

```
 <joint name="Joint_1" type="revolute">
 <origin
 xyz="0 0 -0.008"
 rpy="1.5708 0 0" />
<parent link="base_link" />
<child link="Link_1" />
<axis
xyz="0 1 0" />
<limit
 lower="0"
 upper="3.14"
 effort="0"
 velocity="0" />
</joint>
```

I changed the limit section to this :

```
<limit
lower="0"
upper="3.14"
effort="2"
velocity="2.0" />
```

I have other problems like a very annoying shiver (that comes from effort value I think) but It is not for this topic.

---

Originally posted by [MichaelDUEE](https://answers.ros.org/users/37459/michaelduee/) with karma: 15 on 2019-11-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Seeing this:

```
rospy.init_node('ArmMovement')
pub1=rospy.Publisher("/rrbot/joint1_position_controller/command",Float64,,queue_size=10 )
rate = rospy.Rate(50)
ArmCor1= Float64()
ArmCor1.data=0
pub1.publish(ArmCor1)
rate.sleep()
```

It's likely that there simply isn't any chance for the `Subscriber` (on Gazebo's / `ros_control`'s side) to actually receive the message. `rate.sleep()` is single-shot. There is no periodicity here, so after `1/50` seconds (ie: 20 milliseconds), your program terminates and the `Publisher` is destroyed with it.

In those 20 milliseconds, the `Subscriber` needs to:

1. become aware of your `Publisher`
2. register interest with the ROS master
3. request a subscription
4. set up the actual network connection
5. negotiate with the `Publisher` to see whether it can actually exchange messages
6. complete negotiation, and only *then*
7. can it receive the message

Just to see whether this is indeed the problem, at a `rospy.sleep(5)` after the `pub1=rospy.Publisher(..)` line.

If things start working, you'll want to either make your script periodic, or use a state-based approach (ie: check there are subscribers) with [rospy.Publisher.get_num_connections()](http://docs.ros.org/api/rospy/html/rospy.topics.Topic-class.html#get_num_connections).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-11-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MichaelDUEE](https://answers.ros.org/users/37459/michaelduee/) on 2019-11-05**:
@gvdhoorn I made a while loop and still got the same results. I used echo to see if the message was published and the message was published.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-11-07**:
Then I would suggest to not use a loop, but check with `get_num_connections()` you actually have subscribers. This would both make things state-based, as well as verify that you're publishing to the correct topic.